# How do I launch a web browser on my local machine that visits websites through the ip of a remote machine?

Tags: command-line, networking, ssh

So, I want to visit a website that only permits access to computers from certain ip domains.  My ip is not from one of the allowed domains, but I've ssh'd into a (linux) machine at another location that is at one of the allowed domains.

> How do I launch a web browser on my local machine that visits websites through the ip of the remote machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SSH tunneling in Clemens' answer will work for one specific website, with caveats... if the site does virtual hosting, where the content depends on your HTTP request pointing at a specific hostname, simple port tunneling won't work. And it will only get you to the one site.

A more robust solution is to use OpenSSH dynamic port forwarding. The command would be:

```
ssh -D 1080 ssh-server.example.com
```

Next, set the browser on your client to use a SOCKS proxy at 127.0.0.1, port 1080.

Now, regardless of which site you're visiting, all of your browsing activity (including DNS lookups) will use the remote server.

More detail is here: [SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding: Dynamic Port Forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Dynamic_Port_Forwarding)

If you need to switch frequently between browsing normally and browsing through the remote SSH server, look into installing a plugin for your browser to do fast proxy switching. There are a lot of them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use SSH tunneling to build a TCP tunnel from your Client to the SSH server and route your traffic through this tunnel.

If your private IP on the SSH server Side that you want to access is 192.0.2.1 and your ssh server is ssh.example.com, you can use a SSH command like this:

`ssh -L 8080:192.0.2.1:80 ssh.example.com`

When this ssh connection is established you can point your local browser to `http://localhost:8080` and you should see the page that you would have seen when browsing to `http://192.0.2.1` in the private net.

Comment: So if I wanted to go to `http://www.google.com` in my browser but (hypothetically) Google only lets people go to that page if they have an IP from `example.com`, I'd ssh into the computer I know at `example.com`, log in, then use the ssh command in your answer, open my browser, and go to `http://www.google.com`?

Comment: not exactly, you connect to example.com with the command above. Then you would point your browser to `http://localhost:8080`. But I think the solution provided by Steven is better. I didn't know about this.